# Determine m such that this equation has sense

Tags: abstract-algebra

$$[2]_m + [15]_m = [7]_m + [2]_m$$

My attempt:

$$[17]_m = [9]_m$$

The solutions should be all such that $GCD(17,m)|9$ but this doesn't look correct. Any tip?

Comment: You can simplify this to $[8]_{m} = [0]_{m}$, i.e. $8 \equiv 0 \pmod m$, so $m$ can be any divisor of $8$.

Comment: What is $[a]_m$ Please?

Comment: Equivalence class of [a] with congruence equivalence.

Comment: So $m=1$ is a trivial solution?

Comment: You must have $17\equiv 9\iff 8+9\equiv 9$ It follows $m=8,4,2,1$